# Is there a way to add a Recaptcha field to a Cognito form?

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to add a Recaptcha field to my Cognito form.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Asking _why_ Cognito does not have a recaptcha field is off-topic for [webapps.se]. I have edited your question to ask only if there's a way to add it. And please edit the question to include more detail (what have you tried, etc).

Answer (score 2):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms.  **Yes**, your forms all have a smart **Recaptcha built in**.  Most users will never see it, but bots will!

If for some reason you have issues relating to bot spam, please submit this as a [Bug Report](https://www.cognitoforms.com/bugreport).

If you would like to have Recaptcha always appear for all users, please submit this as a [Feature Request](https://www.cognitoforms.com/featurerequest).